# crawling wikipedia pages with jsoup by href

Tags: java, regex, web-crawler, jsoup, wikipedia

i'm trying to get urls from wikipedia pages in jsoup by this ligne code :

```
Elements linksOnPage = document.select("a[href~=\"/wiki/\"(([A-Za-z])*|_)]");
```

to get links look like : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Stat or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_people ....etc , but it doesn't work for me , so i'm looking to get links from  tag that match : /wiki/[A-Za-z]*|_
and not somthing like this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Administrators%27_noticeboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a couple ideas about your task:

1. It seems, you don't need only articles that contains only latin letters, so list of allowed characters could be extended to digits etc.
2. Basically, what your current regexp says is "give me '/wiki/', then give me either underscore or sequence of english letters of any length", so it makes sense to remove 'or' clause and include underscore inside the list of allowed characters.
3. To avoid special links that contain ':', you can check that regexp match stopped only after it matched the whole href attribute. To achive it, you can put '$' in the end of regexp.

I played a bit with jsoup and something like this parsed from wikipedia pretty much what you were looking for, I think:

```
Elements allInfoLinks = doc.select("a[href~=\\/wiki\\/([a-zA-Z0-9_/&?]+)$]");
```

By the way, in each case you have issues with regular expressions, you may find https://regex101.com/ very useful for debugging

Comment: it's work but i encounter a problem int the recursive function

Comment: look at here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43216310/jsoup-infinite-recursive-crawling-function